# Intuit QuickBooks Web Connector Error

Tags: quickbooks

I have been trying to integrate a PHP based solution with the QuickBooks desktop pro. I am using PHP DevKit for QuickBooks Web Connector.

I have been able to setup the web connector properly however i am not able to make it to connect to application. Every time i get following error message:

```
20151206.12:22:43 UTC   : UpdateThisScheduledApp() : Performing SCHEDULED UPDATE for application = QuickBooks Integrator
20151206.12:22:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE
20151206.12:22:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True
20151206.12:22:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session locked *********************
20151206.12:22:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
20151206.12:22:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: QuickBooks Integrator
20151206.12:22:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): QuickBooks Integrator
20151206.12:22:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: http://localhost/qb/quickbooks-php-master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector.php
20151206.12:22:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20151206.12:22:44 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Actual error received from web service for serverVersion call: <Client foun......
20151206.12:22:44 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : This application does not contain support for serverVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20151206.12:22:44 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:<productVersion="2.2.0.34">
20151206.12:22:44 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : Actual error received from web service for clientVersion call: <Client foun......
20151206.12:22:44 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application does not contain support for clientVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20151206.12:22:44 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'QuickBooks Integrator', username = 'quickbooks'
20151206.12:22:45 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:<userName="quickbooks"><password=<MaskedForSecurity>
20151206.12:22:45 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
Client fou......
20151206.12:22:45 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20151206.12:22:45 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20151206.12:22:45 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdate() : Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details.
20151206.12:22:45 UTC   : UpdateThisScheduledApp() : QBWC1031: Update completed with some error. Application has been notified of the error accordingly. See QWCLog for further information.
```

[image]

VERBOSE Logging logs:

```
20151207.15:38:23 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : updateWS() for application = 'QuickBooks Integrator' has STARTED
20151207.15:38:23 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE
20151207.15:38:23 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True
20151207.15:38:23 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session locked *********************
20151207.15:38:23 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
20151207.15:38:23 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: QuickBooks Integrator
20151207.15:38:23 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): QuickBooks Integrator
20151207.15:38:23 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: http://localhost/qb/quickbooks-php-master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector.php
20151207.15:38:23 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20151207.15:38:23 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Actual error received from web service for serverVersion call: <Response is not well-formed XML.>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-serverVersion.
20151207.15:38:24 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : This application does not contain support for serverVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20151207.15:38:24 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:<productVersion="2.2.0.34">
20151207.15:38:24 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : Actual error received from web service for clientVersion call: <Response is not well-formed XML.>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-clientVersion.
20151207.15:38:24 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application does not contain support for clientVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20151207.15:38:24 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'QuickBooks Integrator', username = 'quickbooks'
20151207.15:38:24 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:<userName="quickbooks"><password=<MaskedForSecurity>
20151207.15:38:24 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
Response is not well-formed XML.
More info:
StackTrace =    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebServiceDoc.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebService.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.authenticate(String UserName, String Password)
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_authenticate(String& ticket, String& companyFileName)
Source = System.Web.Services
20151207.15:38:24 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20151207.15:38:24 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20151207.15:38:24 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details.
```

Comment: Turn the Web Connector to VERBOSE logging and post the log after running it with VERBOSE logging. http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector#setting_the_web_connector_to_use_verbose_logging_mode  Also, post the actual error message the Web Connector GUI is showing.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. Error at GUI screenshot is added in the question and also the logs after running the connector in VERBOSE logging.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you see this:

> Response is not well-formed XML.

There's about a 99.9% chance you have a PHP or SQL error.

- Did you check your PHP error log? What does it say?
- What do you see if you visit the URL the Web Connector is hitting in a browser? Do you see any errors?

Comment: I haven't checked PHP error logs but when i visit the URL on browser i see following warnings: 1. Warning - Deprecated: mysql_connect(). 2. Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\xampp\htdocs\qb\quickbooks-php-master\QuickBooks\Driver\Sql\Mysql.php:289) in D:\xampp\htdocs\qb\quickbooks-php-master\QuickBooks\WebConnector\Server.php on line 325

Comment: I haven't changed any file other than example_web_connector.php. Also there is no PHP code that i have added, I am just testing the connectovity between the two.

Comment: @Saurabh  OK, so fix the error. Either turn off error reporting so that PHP isn't spitting out error messages, or change the $dsn string to use a non-deprecated extension.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue with [example_web_connector.php](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector.php) file so I changed line 40 to this

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```